# Can't get my button to move in Objective C after it has been clicked. Timer and count ++ seem to bother it

Tags: ios

I am building a very basic game in xcode. Basically - you need to tap the button as many times as possible within 30 seconds,

I've added the code to count how many times the button is pressed, and added the code to countdown the timer label from 30 secs.

However - I want to make the game slightly better, by having the 'tap me' button moving around the screen when it is pressed.

I found a piece of code online that makes a button randomly move around the screen once pressed. But since I added it to my code, it doesn't work.

I removed the count++ in the button method, and it works, but goes back to it's original place ever second the timer is reducing.

I removed the timer, and the button works fine, and every time it is pressed it's on a different section of the screen.

My question is, why is the code being affecting by the timer - updating a label, and has no link to the button, and why can't I count the times the button is pressed and move the button at the same time?

I have attached my code below for reference - any constructive help will be great!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController;

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self setUpGame];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setUpGame];
}



- (void)setUpGame {
    seconds = 30;
    count = 0;

    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %li", (long)seconds];
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%li", (long)count];


    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(subtractTime)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

-(void)subtractTime {
    seconds --;
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %li", (long)seconds];

    if (seconds == 0) {
        [timer invalidate];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Time is up!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %li points", (long)count] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again?" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed{

    count++;

    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score\n%li", (long)count];

    _button.center = CGPointMake(arc4random() %100, arc4random() %200);


}
```

and

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;



    NSInteger count;
    NSInteger seconds;
    NSTimer *timer;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;


- (IBAction)buttonPressed;






@end
```

Comment: This is probably due to auto layout. If you use auto layout in IB (it's on by default), then you shouldn't move or resize views by setting frames, but by adjusting the constraints. Anything that causes the view to redraw itself, will cause the views to move back to the positions defined by their constraints.

Comment: Thank you - it was the auto layout setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think rdelmar's idea is right. If so, you could do the following:
In storyboard, give the button the constraints: fixed width, fixed height, fixed leading space to superview & fixed top space to superview.
Instead of setting the center property of your button (which will be overwritten by autolayout), define in your code two properties

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leadingSpaceConstraint;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topSpaceConstraint;
```

and link these properties to your constraints in storyboard.
Where you changed the center property before, change now these constraints something like

```
self.leadingSpaceConstraint.constant = ... // some random value within reasonable limits
self.topSpaceConstraint.constant = ... // some random value within reasonable limits
```

followed by

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ // some reasonable value instead of 1.0
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```